# variable in useState not updating in useEffect callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm having an issue while using useState and useEffect hooks

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const counter = ({ count, speed }) => {
    const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {

        const counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if(inc < count){
                setInc(inc + 1);
            }else{
                clearInterval(counterInterval);
            }
        }, speed);

    }, [count]);

    return inc;
}

export default counter;
```

Above code is a counter component, it takes count in props, then initializes inc with 0 and increments it till it becomes equal to count

The issue is I'm not getting the updated value of inc in useEffect's and setInterval's callback every time I'm getting 0, so it renders inc as 1 and setInterval never get clear. I think inc must be in closure of use useEffect's and setInterval's callback so I must get the update inc there, So maybe it's a bug?

I can't pass inc in dependency ( which is suggested in other similar questions ) because in my case, I've setInterval in useEffect so passing inc in dependency array is causing an infinite loop

I have a working solution using a stateful component, but I want to achieve this using functional component

Comment: Is there any explanation for the downvote?

Comment: Try using the callback to use the latest value: `setInc(inc => inc + 1);`. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Please show us how you use this hook then

Comment: Note that your hook can't be so simple as useEffect needs `speed` and `inc` as dependencies and that you should return a function to clear the interval

Comment: @Alvaro, I tried using setInc(inc => inc + 1); now I'm getting updated inc in setInc's callback, but still not getting updated inc in setInterval's callback so it's never entering in else condition causing an infinite loop

Comment: @adesurirey, I've mentioned in the question that I'm using setInterval in useEffect so passing inc will cause an infinite loop

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. You're not returning a function from `useEffect` to clear the interval
2. Your `inc` value is out of sync because you're not using the previous value of `inc`.

One option:

```
const counter = ({ count, speed }) => {
    const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
            setInc(inc => {
                if(inc < count){
                    return inc + 1;
                }else{
                    // Make sure to clear the interval in the else case, or 
                    // it will keep running (even though you don't see it)
                    clearInterval(counterInterval);
                    return inc;
                }
            });
        }, speed);

        // Clear the interval every time `useEffect` runs
        return () => clearInterval(counterInterval);

    }, [count, speed]);

    return inc;
}
```

Another option is to include `inc` in the deps array, this makes things simpler since you don't need to use the previous `inc` inside `setInc`:

```
const counter = ({ count, speed }) => {
    const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if(inc < count){
                return setInc(inc + 1);
            }else{
                // Make sure to clear your interval in the else case,
                // or it will keep running (even though you don't see it)
                clearInterval(counterInterval);
            }
        }, speed);

        // Clear the interval every time `useEffect` runs
        return () => clearInterval(counterInterval);

    }, [count, speed, inc]);

    return inc;
}
```

There's even a *third* way that's even simpler:
Include `inc` in the deps array and if `inc >= count`, return early before calling `setInterval`:

```
    const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inc >= count) return;

        const counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
          setInc(inc + 1);
        }, speed);

        return () => clearInterval(counterInterval);
    }, [count, speed, inc]);

    return inc;
```

Comment: option one : else case is returning inc then clearing setInterval so that line will never get executed and will cause infinite loop

Comment: All your options are working perfectly, thanks for your answer, there is one issue in second option if should return setInc(inc + 1)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the callback from `clearInterval` is defined every time `useEffect` runs, which is when `count` updates. The value `inc` had when defined is the one that will be read in the callback.

This edit has a different approach. We include a ref to keep track of `inc` being less than `count`, if it is less we can continue incrementing `inc`. If it is not, then we clear the counter (as you had in the question). Every time `inc` updates, we evaluate if it is still lesser than count and save it in the `ref`. This value is then used in the previous `useEffect`.

I included a dependency to `speed` as @DennisVash correctly indicates in his answer.

```
const useCounter = ({ count, speed }) => {
    const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);
    const inc_lt_count = useRef(inc < count);

    useEffect(() => {
        const counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (inc_lt_count.current) {
                setInc(inc => inc + 1);
            } else {
                clearInterval(counterInterval);
            }
        }, speed);

        return () => clearInterval(counterInterval);
    }, [count, speed]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inc < count) {
            inc_lt_count.current = true;
        } else {
            inc_lt_count.current = false;
        }
    }, [inc, count]);

    return inc;
};
```

Comment: @DennisVash Thanks for letting me know, could you please expand on why it won't work?

Comment: Did you check it? There are plenty of reasons, the main one is that increasing reference won't cause re-render

Comment: Actually, In Parent Component (where I'm using Counter) value of count is coming from the server that's why I've added it in dependency array, I can remove its dependency by mounting Counter component after API call. So useEffect will work as componentDidMount. Now using useRef is not going to rerender component. So i need state to rerender component

Comment: inc.current value is getting update, but react is not rerendering it, as it's not in state

Comment: @AbhaySehgal this is what I meant with "side-effects". So you need `inc` inside a state. Ok, let me edit.

Comment: @AbhaySehgal I included a different approach.

Comment: @Alvaro I tried your solution, It works perfectly, but there is one issue if you pass speed as 0 ( which maybe never gonna happen ) then inc gets increment to (count + 1) may be due to async nature of setInterval

Comment: @AbhaySehgal. Im glad it helped. As far as I understand, `setInterval` will always run, if its `0` then it will only run one time. I have a doubt which shouldnt affect this case, but its something to consider and test out. If the interval time is shorter than the time the component takes to render, it might run more than 1 time before the state updates. But Im not really sure this would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The main problems that need to be dealt with are [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and clearing interval on a condition which depends on props.

You should add the conditional check within the functional `setState`:

```
setInc(inc => (inc < count ? inc + 1 : inc));
```

Also, the clearing interval should happen on unmount.

If you want to add `clearInterval` on condition (`inc < count`), you need to save references for the interval id and the increased number:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const useCounter = ({ count, speed }) => {
  const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);

  const incRef = useRef(inc);
  const idRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    idRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setInc(inc => (inc < count ? inc + 1 : inc));
      incRef.current++;
    }, speed);

    return () => clearInterval(idRef.current);
  }, [count, speed]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (incRef.current > count) {
      clearInterval(idRef.current);
    }
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(incRef.current);
  });

  return inc;
};

const App = () => {
  const inc = useCounter({ count: 10, speed: 1000 });
  return <h1>Counter : {inc}</h1>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit Q-59017467-DepCounter]

Comment: This might work for this particular use case but will cause bugs if the component re-renders too often: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Can you reproduce any bug?

Comment: try console.log() in setInc function, it's calling infinitely

Comment: It will run until unmount, I guess you want to clear interval on condition, let me fix it

Comment: @AbhaySehgal I edited the answer, now it clears on count condition