# Fully functioning countdown timer using React hooks only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here's my code. You can also check it out on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1v6uvc?file=src/App.js):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Timer = ({
    initialHours = 10,
    initialMinutes = 0,
    initialSeconds = 0,
}) => {
    const [hours, setHours] = useState(initialHours);
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(initialMinutes);
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(initialSeconds);

    let myInterval;

    const startTimer = () => {
        myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (seconds > 0) {
                setSeconds(seconds - 1);
            }
            if (seconds === 0) {
                if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0) {
                    clearInterval(myInterval);
                } else if (minutes > 0) {
                    setMinutes(minutes - 1);
                    setSeconds(59);
                } else if (hours > 0) {
                    setHours(hours - 1);
                    setMinutes(59);
                    setSeconds(59);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
        cancelTimer();
    };
    const cancelTimer = () => {
        return () => {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        };
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className='timer'>
                {hours < 10 && hours !== 0 ? `0${hours}:` : hours >= 10 && `${hours}:`}
                {minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:
                {seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
            </h1>
            <button onClick={startTimer}>START</button>
            <button>PAUSE</button>
            <button>RESUME</button>
            <button onClick={cancelTimer}>CANCEL</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Timer;
```

I'm having trouble with the **START** button and this is what it looks like when I click on the **START** button multiple times:
[image]

You'll notice that on the first click the number never continues to go down unless I click on the `START` button again and again but it would look like a broken slot machine. And if I hit on the `CANCEL` button, it should stop the timer and reset back to the set time, but it doesn't. I don't know how to solve the problem for this 2 buttons, and much more for the `PAUSE` and `RESUME`. I don't know how to make them work, too. Please help.

Comment: Besides from the React component specific issues, you should not use `setInterval` for something like that. It doesn't guarantee that the callback is called *exactly* every second. Instead you want to build something around [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and update the countdown based on the time that has elapsed between calls. This might give some inspiration: https://www.artmann.co/articles/building-a-javascript-countdown-timer . I'm sure you'll find some questions/posts about using rAF with React.

Comment: Hello @Felix. I believe you and I see what you mean with the `setInterval` not able to `guarantee that the callback is called exactly every second`. And I've seen a code that logged the time of callback of setInterval on the console that proves that. But could you please at least try to convert Abhay's code below from using `setInterval` to `requestAnimationFrame`? I'd really appreciate that, and of course, those who will see this question in the future would, too:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Felix Kling you can try a different approach, to check why your code is not working check the below code, I've made some changes in your Timer component :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Timer = ({
    initialHours = 10,
    initialMinutes = 0,
    initialSeconds = 0,
}) => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState({
        h: initialHours,
        m: initialMinutes,
        s: initialSeconds,
    });

    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

    const startTimer = () => {
        let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            setTime((time) => {
                const updatedTime = { ...time };
                if (time.s > 0) {
                    updatedTime.s--;
                }

                if (time.s === 0) {
                    if (time.h === 0 && time.m === 0) {
                        clearInterval(myInterval);
                    } else if (time.m > 0) {
                        updatedTime.m--;
                        updatedTime.s = 59;
                    } else if (updatedTime.h > 0) {
                        updatedTime.h--;
                        updatedTime.m = 59;
                        updatedTime.s = 59;
                    }
                }

                return updatedTime;
            });
        }, 1000);
        setTimer(myInterval);
    };

    const pauseTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };

    const cancelTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
        setTime({
            h: initialHours,
            m: initialMinutes,
            s: initialSeconds,
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className='timer'>
                {time.h < 10 && time.h !== 0
                    ? `0${time.h}:`
                    : time.h >= 10 && `${time.h}:`}
                {time.m < 10 ? `0${time.m}` : time.m}:
                {time.s < 10 ? `0${time.s}` : time.s}
            </h1>
            <button onClick={startTimer}>START</button>
            <button onClick={pauseTimer}>PAUSE</button>
            <button onClick={cancelTimer}>CANCEL</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Timer;
```

Explanation:

1. in your startTimer function in the last line you're calling cancelTimer
2. When you're working with hooks then keep in mind you won't get updated value of state variable until you use function inside a set function like I'm doing in setTime and in that callback, you'll get an updated value as a first parameter
3. In cancelTimer method you're returning a function you've to call clearInterval also myInterval is undefined in cancelTimer so I've set it's value in state

For more information and other ways [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017467/variable-in-usestate-not-updating-in-useeffect-callback)

Comment: Thanks for this and for the explanation @Abhay! I really appreciate it. The `START` button worked. But there seems to be a problem with the `CANCEL` button. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Alright @Abhay. Thanks! It works! I just realized that the `START` button works the same as the `RESUME` button, am I right? (Please correct me if that's wrong). So I'll do something about that. But about the `PAUSE` button, do I clear the interval and then set the state of time to whatever's on the time left? Do you have a way to do this, please?

Comment: PAUSE will be same as cancelTimer only difference will be it won't reset the time in state, It'll just clear the setInterval

Comment: Thanks @Abhay. I included the pauseTimer func in your code.